# How to use Expectation Maximization (EM) in Item Response Theory (IRT)?

Tags: statistics, optimization, expectation, parameter-estimation

Could you give a worked example on the steps of Expectation Maximization in Item Response Theory if we use the Two Parameter Rasch Model.

The student abilities are **unknown** and the question parameters are **unknown as well**. How can we use Expectation Maximization (EM) to find these unknown parameters if we know what questions each student has got correct.

(note: I have found a two sources online but I do not understand them. A worked example would be fantastic: http://www.openirt.com/b-a-h/papers/note9801.pdf and http://www.lsac.org/docs/default-source/research-(lsac-resources)/rr-11-01.pdf?sfvrsn=2)